# Recover chrome history scrubbed by adware

Tags: google-chrome, history, adware

I've found different adware installed on my home comp a few times now, trying to track down if my wife or kids are installing it. Or worse. While trying to replay the history to figure out the cause, I'm running into some weird things.

- Chrome history doesn't show it when scrolling through
- Chrome history does show it when searching for the adware "fromdoctopdf", but then just it nothing before or after (see first image below)
- I used a Chrome extension to export the complete history to JSON, it has no entries at all from the date in question, March 27 (see second image)

Any thoughts as to how to recover the complete, play-by-play history? Or better ways to figure out how this adware keeps getting installed?

**History while searching**

[image: history while searching]

**JSON history hole**

[image: json history hole]

*redacted timestamps because, why not*